# Reusing ajax function

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I want to reuse this function but I want to change the id everytime (in this case brand), do I have to make the function all over again each time or is there another way?

This is the function:

```
        function showUser(str)
    {
    if (str=="")
      {
      document.getElementById("brand").innerHTML="";
      return;
      } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("brand").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","inc/form_rest.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

Comment: Less than `0.34%` of people on the internet still use IE5 and IE6. It's safe to get rid of the `new ActiveXObject` call.

Answer (score 2):

Pass in the id as a parameter of the function?

Comment: No problem. And don't feel too bad, I do stuff like that all the time. In the heat of the moment the simple things often escape us.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the id as parameter...

```
function showUser(str, id) {
    if (str=="") {
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML="";
      return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","inc/form_rest.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```